# Why can't I define STATUS as a constant?

Tags: php, constants

When I define STATUS, it defaults to 0. Yet all the other constants work.

```
define('LOCATION',07);
define('STATUS',08);
echo 'x'.STATUS."x\n";exit;
define('TERM_DATE',09);

$ php synchronize.php
x0x
```

Comment: Try using quotes for `08` => `define('STATUS',"08");` and for `09` etc.  Leading zeros are treated as octals. http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php `define("FOO",     "something");` - `define('MIN_VALUE', '0.0');`

Comment: You can define `STATUS` as a constant and you do it. The problem is that `08` is a number represented using the [octal notation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) and it is not valid (because there is no `8` digit in base 8).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code works fine! But where your problem is, you defined it as a octal value and `08` is an invalid octal value so everything after it gets removed and 0 remains.

You can read more about this here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

And a quote from there:

> **Warning:**
>   If an invalid digit is given in an octal integer (i.e. **8** or 9), the **rest of the number is ignored.**

So you can define it as a string, e.g.

```
define('STATUS', "08");
               //^  ^ See the quotes
```

Or define it as a valid octal number. (Same thing for: `define('TERM_DATE',09);`)

Comment: True if you want 08 defined in status you'll need to assign it as a string `define('STATUS','08');`

Comment: Shoot. I used 0s to line up the numbers when I was making the list.

Comment: @Chloe Now you have to remove them or use them as a string if you want the 0 in there